# jquery ui drag event to cancel click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Ok, so I have these draggable elements, that also have click event handlers. The problem is that the click event is firing (and handled) when I drag the element, but what I wanted is to **handle the click only when there's no dragging** going on, so when the element is dragged, cancel the click event handling.

Here's a **demo fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/wsTY5/

```
$('div.map').draggable(options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it with something like this:

```
var clicked = true;
var options = {
    containment: '.map-containment',
    cursor: 'move',
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        clicked = false;
    }
};

$('div.map').draggable(options);

var counter = 0;

var $span = $('#ClickCounter > span');
var $dummies = $('.dummy');
$dummies.click(function(){
    if(clicked){
        $span.html(++counter);
    }
    clicked = true;
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/wsTY5/1/

**Update**

Sometimes when you drag it does not register the click event depending on where you end the dragging.

```
var options = {
    containment: '.map-containment',
    cursor: 'move',
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        clicked = false;
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            clicked = true;  
        },10);
    }
};
```

So I added the `stop` function to the options just to make sure that it would count clicks once you stop dragging.

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/wsTY5/3/

Comment: @fduayer I'm seeing a little weird behavior where sometimes the click does not go through.. going to look into it a little more.  I may have an update.

Comment: @fduayer check my update for a better solution.  Thanks

Comment: @Trevor I'd recommend changing the `$dummies.click` listener to a `$dummies.on('mouseup')` listener.